# SetWithCopyWarning Anomaly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Slightly different question than you guys may be used to seeing in regards to the pandas SetWithCopyWarning. In order to better facilitate my understanding, I've been actively trying to generate this warning and have actually had trouble...but I stumbled onto two interesting block of code, which I believe should both generate the setwithcopy code but only one does:

Creating the Dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5))
```

Following code generates a SetWithCopyWarning as expected:

```
df2=df.loc[:,:3]
df2.loc[0,0] = 99
```

This line of code has one small difference and does not generate a SetWithCopyWarning:

```
df2=df.loc[:4,:3]
df2.loc[0,0] = 99
```

Why does only changing the first index item in .loc on the first row from ":" to ":4" fail to generate a SetWithCopyWarning? Even though both are pulling all rows labeled 0-4?

Edited to make my code pop out more.

Comment: The [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) say "Outside of simple cases, it’s very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy" - so you might be able to work it out for this specific case but in general you need to figure out how to write code that will never run into this ambiguity.